# Kubernetes | Rolling Update on Replica Set

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to perform a rolling update of the container image that my Federated Replica Set is using but I'm getting the following error:

When I run: `kubectl rolling-update mywebapp -f mywebapp-v2.yaml`

I get the error message: `the server could not find the requested resource`;

This is a brand new and clean install on Google Container Engine (GKE) so besides creating the Federated Cluster and deploying my first service nothing else has been done. I'm following the instructions from the [Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/#examples) but no luck.

I've checked to make sure that I'm in the correct context and I've also created a new YAML file pointing to the new image and updated the metadata name. Am I missing something? The easy way for me to do this is to delete the replica set and then redeploy but then I'm cheating myself :). Any pointers would be appreciated

mywebappv2.yaml - new yaml file for rolling update

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: mywebapp-v2
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mywebapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mywebapp
          image: gcr.io/xxxxxx/static-js:v2
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: mywebapp
```

My original mywebapp.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: mywebapp
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mywebapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mywebapp
          image: gcr.io/xxxxxx/static-js:v2
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: mywebapp
```

Comment: Could you try if  'kind:ReplicationController' works?

Comment: Unfortunately the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `kind: Deployment`.

> Most [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/) commands that support Replication Controllers also
>   support ReplicaSets. One exception is the [rolling-update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.8/#rolling-update) command. If
>   you want the rolling update functionality please consider using
>   [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) instead.
>
> Also, the rolling-update command is imperative
>   whereas Deployments are declarative, so we recommend using Deployments
>   through the [rollout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.8/#rollout) command.
>
> -- [Replica Sets |
>   Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#how-to-use-a-replicaset)

Comment: Thanks for that @silverfox. Replication controllers, replica sets, deployments - so many different replications to choose from :(!! So should I still create a new deployment file with the new image information or just use the existing?

Comment: Well, it works either way. create deployment with the existing, and then `kubectl set image deployment/mywebapp mywebapp=gcr.io/xxxxxx/static-js:v3` is ok. Take a look at [Updating a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)